# How do I fix a distorted texture? (I'm trying to import a blender obj to join it with a sims 4 object mesh)

Tags: texturing, import

So I'm using blender 2.7 and I made a biscuit tin for sims 4 (picture 1) and exported it as an object. To work in the sims 4 it now needs to be joined with the mesh of an existing sims object.

[image]

Now I have opened the sims 4 mesh in blender, and imported my biscuit tin object. But, the texture wasn't appearing (image 2) So I pressed N and changed it from GLSL to multitexture. Now the texture is showing up but it is distorted and see through (images 3 & 4)

Does anyone know how I fix this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like the normals might be facing the wring direction. Go to edit mode, select all, then `mesh > normal > recalculate outside`.

Comment: Ahh perfect - that's it fixed! Thank you so much!